# Remove package using terminal on Mac

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I installed a package (asciiart) a while ago but it appears that it did not install properly or is currently not working due to updates. Even the help command doesn't appear to be working:

```
$ asciiart -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /usr/local/bin/asciiart:23:in `<main>'
    12: from /usr/local/bin/asciiart:23:in `load'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rasciiart-0.0.9/bin/asciiart:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rasciiart-0.0.9/lib/asciiart.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/lib/RMagick.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.9.10 but ImageMagick 6.9.11-7 is in use. (RuntimeError)
```

I couldn't find any documentation to remove this package. Is it possible to remove this package so that the `asciiart` command will not be recognized (i.e. I will get the standard `-bash: asciiart: command not found` error message instead)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched on Github using https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&o=desc&q=asciiart&s=updated&type=Repositories, and discovered that this is a `ruby` package so I was able to remove it using

```
sudo gem uninstall asciiart
```